# how to fix "the type or namespace name "system" could not be found are you missing directive or assembly reference (CS0246) "

Tags: .net, .net-core

I am trying to install .net core sdk in my visual studio code. after the .net core sdk install by using dotnet restore command i get the such problem. how i can solve the problem?

```cs
using System;
namespace BRT.BLL.Model
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Generic response model
    /// </summary>
    public class ApiResponse
    {
        //result status codes, 200,400..
        public ApiResponse(int statusCode, object result, string type,
            string message, bool isSuccess)
        {
            this.StatusCode = statusCode;
            this.Result = result;
            this.Type = type;
            this.Message = message;
            this.IsSuccess = isSuccess;

        }
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
        //dynamic data result 
        public object Result { get; set; }
        //type of the dynamic data
        public string Type { get; set; }
        //custome message
        public string Message { get; set; }
        //if the request is successful or not
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
}
```

predefined type "system.Int32" is not defined or imported and other related problem

Comment: A problem with `System.Int32` sounds like a problem either with your csproj, or your build tools install; at the command-line in the relevant folder, what does `dotnet --version` say? And: in your csproj, what is your `<TargetFramework>` (or `<TargetFrameworks>`)?

Comment: dotnet --version 2.2.401
 and TargetFramework 2.0

Comment: "2.0" isn't a valid framework moniker. You'd normally use netcoreapp2.0 or netstandard2.0, for example. It's possible that that's the problem. Please post your project file.

Comment: it is working now but i face with the problem "project file does not exist",when i try to run the project

Answer (score 0):

I often get this with new projects. A simple clean, restore nuget packages and rebuild normally fixes it fine. If you've recently install a new version of Net Core, it helps to reboot your PC too.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue with Visual Studio 2019  and .net core sdk 2.2.0.

These steps I solved the problem:

- Close the Visual Studio
- Open the Visual Studio as Administrator
- Open the Solution
- Right click on Solution -> Restore NuGet Packages

Answer (score -3):

Try:

1º Restore nugget package

2º Restart your computer

But if that don't work, and i hope it does

3º install Visual Studio from the beginning

Comment: 10Qs a lot it  is working  now.but i face with the problem "project file does not exist" when i try to run the project.

Comment: Check the build logs to see where the build agent is downloading the source, and compare it to where MSBuild is looking for solution file. Sometimes, there appears to be a difference between the location of source and where MSBuild is starts searching for the solution file and the error occurs.